# React - why does the main JS bundle size differ between users?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm using Webpack to bundle my main React JS code, and i recently started logging the size of this file using the Resources API.

I know that if the JS bundle has a size of 0 it means it was served from the browser cache, but why does the size change between my users?
It could be 300kb, 546KB, 1.2MB and everything in between.
Why is that? Shouldn't it be either its actual size (which is a single value) or 0 if it was served from cache?

Comment: Could it be that different users have cached different numbers of files? Especially since webpack does code splitting.

Comment: This is specifically for the `main.[someHash].min.js` file.

Comment: As long as it's the same file being served to all users then there should be no difference.

Comment: maaaybe some are downloading different compressed versions of the asset? like if a browser prefer protli or gzip and you have those versions then users may have different compressed size (though the final size should be always the same)